# Populate Fields From one Controller, in another.. CAKEPHP

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am currently trying to allow the users to archive events that have already been completed.

Then the event will be viewed in the Archive Table.

So basically I have one archive table, and one event table, and when the user wants to archive the event, they should be able to view the event in the archive add form (which needs to be populated by the $id of the event).

But I do not know how to populate the field.. I have tried setting a value.. but the events are not sessions so that didn't work, and I have also tried setting the $id at the start of the form, but that also didn't work.

Here is the code to my archive function in the events controller.

```
   public function archive($id = null) {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $event = $this->Event->read($id);
            $archive['Archive'] = $event['Event'];
            $archive['Archive']['eventID'] = $archive['Archive']['archiveID'];
            unset($archive['Archive']['archiveID']);
            $this->loadModel('Archive');
            $this->Archive->create();
            if ($this->Archive->save($archive)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The event has been archived'));
                $this->Event->delete($id);
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'eventmanage'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The event could not be archived. Please, contact the administrator.'));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do one of the following:

**Set the values for the fields using `$this->request->data` in the controller.**

```
public function add($id = null) {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        [..snip..]
    }
    $this->loadModel('Event');
    $event = $this->Event->read($id);
    $this->request->data['Archive'] = $event['Event'];
}
```

OR

**Update the form to set the values.**

Update the existing code with the same event read:

```
public function add($id = null) {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        [..snip..]
    }
    $this->loadModel('Event');
    $this->set('event', $this->Event->read($id));
}
```

Then in your form in the Archives/add.ctp file, update each input to reflect the value of the $event.

```
echo $this->Form->input('eventID', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $event['Event']['id']));
```

OR

**Write a function that will move the record.**

Put a button on the Event View called 'Archive'. Create a method in the Event Controller that will archive the event.

```
public function archive($id = null) {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $event = $this->Event->read($id);
        $archive['Archive'] = $event['Event'];
        $archive['Archive']['event_id'] = $archive['Archive']['id'];
        unset($archive['Archive']['id']);
        $this->loadModel('Archive');
        $this->Archive->create();
        if ($this->Archive->save($archive)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The event has been archived'));
            $this->Event->delete($id);
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The event could not be archived. Please, contact the administrator.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Chuck, with your second option,in which page, and where does '$this->set('event', $this->Event->read($id));' go?

Comment: In the same ArchiveController.add method after the if statement in the same location as option 1. Just keep in mind that the user will be able to modify fields before archiving if you do that.

Comment: thanks for your help Chuck, im getting one error now, "Undefined variable: event" i will update my code above as well so you can see what i have done

Comment: You may need to update your array: `$event['id']` to `$event['Event']['id']`. Also, you need to move the `$this->set('event'..` outside the `if ($post)` or it will never get set.

Comment: i now receive the following error: 'Fatal error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object in /homepages/3/d439567456/htdocs/cakephp/app/Controller/ArchivesController.php on line 38'   Any ideas?

Comment: It means you are not loading the Event model. Try adding `$this->loadModel('Event');` right before the read. (Updated above.)

Comment: hmm, its getting there, no errors.. but the fields are not populating. :/

Comment: Did you confirm the $event variable contained information? Try adding a `<?php pr($event); ?>` to the view (or print_r if debug is not on). Also, confirm that ALL fields were updated with `$event['Event']`. Your code in the question shows a few fields that are not updated.

Comment: when i check to see if the $event variable contained information, the print_r($event) came back empty. 

I have now added the `$event['event']` to all the fields as well. Any idea why it holds no information?

Comment: This means the data is not getting set when you read it from the database. So verify the `$id` on `$this->Event->read($id)` to make sure you are passing the correct id for the event you are trying to read.

Comment: i updated my Add function so that you can see what it looks like, i added the $this->Event->read ($id); but im not getting a Fatal error: Call to a member function read(). Thank you for your patients..

Comment: Take out the `$this->Event->read($id);` at the top of the function, verify the `$id` is being passed correctly, and you should have it.

Comment: the $id is not being passed, the compiler seems to be pointing at `$event` in `$event = $this->Event->id = $id;`

Comment: If the `$id` is not being passed, then you need to make sure you are passing it when you call the function. Something like `http://domainname.com/archives/add/ID`

Comment: I decided to go with your third option, which has worked.. if only i did this 2/3 days a go we would have been a lot further ahead.. haha... THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: arg, turns out it only says it archives the event, and does not actually send the data to the database, i will update my code so you can have a look

Comment: It's not a forum. You should leave the content for this question alone and ask a new one. It will totally ruin the intent of stackoverflow.